# Sorting an Array of Hash by multiple keys Perl

Tags: perl

I have an array referance containing hashes (i.e. @AOH)

```
$arr_ref = [ { 'brand' => 'A',
               'supplier' => 'X',
               'PO' => '2'
              },
              { 'brand' => 'B',
                'supplier' => 'Y',
                'PO' => '1'       
              },
              { 'brand' => 'B',
                'supplier' => 'X',
                'PO' => '2'           
              },
              { 'brand' => 'A',
                'supplier' => 'X',
                'PO' => '1'
              },
              { 'brand' => 'B',
                'supplier' => 'X',
                'PO' => '1'           
              }
];
```

I want to sort it on the basis of all three keys (i.e. brand, supplier and PO).
Order of sorting should be brand first, then supplier and then finally on PO.

array referance after sorting should be:

```
$arr_ref = [ { 'brand' => 'A',
                'supplier' => 'X',
                'PO' => '1'
              },
              { 'brand' => 'A',
               'supplier' => 'X',
               'PO' => '2'
              },
              { 'brand' => 'B',
                'supplier' => 'X',
                'PO' => '1'           
              },
              { 'brand' => 'B',
                'supplier' => 'X',
                'PO' => '2'           
              },              
              { 'brand' => 'B',
                'supplier' => 'Y',
                'PO' => '1'       
              },
];
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since [`<=>` and `cmp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) return 0 to indicate equality, and that's false, and because Perl's logical Boolean operators return the deciding value instead of just 0 or 1, sorting by multiple keys is as easy as stringing multiple comparisons together with `or` or `||`:

```
@$arr_ref = sort { $a->{brand}    cmp $b->{brand}    or 
                   $a->{supplier} cmp $b->{supplier} or 
                   $a->{PO}       <=> $b->{PO} 
                 } @$arr_ref;
```

I'm assuming that PO is a numeric field, so you use `<=>` for it instead of `cmp`.

Comment: Just adding a funny case scenario. I had to assign the return value of the sort {...} to a new array instead of using the old one (@$arr_ref). The former returned empty reference... still not sure why. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The following should sort the array reference and place the array back into the `$arr_ref`:

```
$arr_ref = [sort by_brand_supplier_PO @$arr_ref];

sub by_brand_supplier_PO {
    $a->{brand} cmp $b->{brand} ||
    $a->{supplier} cmp $b->{supplier} ||
    $a->{PO} <=> $b->{PO}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sort::Key::Multi](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Multi), distributed with Sort::Key.

In this case, we're using `ssikeysort`, which expects a block that returns a string, a string and an integer, and which sorts the values by that tuple. (The `s` in `ssi` stands for string and the `i` for integer.)

```
use Sort::Key::Multi qw(ssikeysort);

@$arr_ref = ssikeysort { $_->{brand}, $_->{supplier}, $_->{PO} } @$arr_ref;
```

---

You can also use the in-place variant, which uses less memory:

```
use Sort::Key::Multi qw(ssikeysort_inplace);

ssikeysort_inplace { $_->{brand}, $_->{supplier}, $_->{PO} } @$arr_ref;
```