# Sorting an array of hashes which have alphanumeric values

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, sorting, perl-data-structures

I am facing an issue with sorting an array of hashes; hashes having alphanumeric values by which I need to sort.

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395383/sorting-an-array-of-hash-by-multiple-keys-perl)! My question is an extension of this problem.
I tried the solution in the above question but didn't get the required output.

```
$arr_ref = [
  { brand => "A.1", PO => "1.a", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "A.2", PO => "2.a", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "B.1", PO => "1.b", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "B.2", PO => "2.b", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "B.3", PO => "1.c", supplier => "Y" },
]
```

I need to sort by Brand or PO.

```
#sort the array reference and place the array back into the standard_set
$arr_ref = [sort by_brand @$arr_ref];
sub by_brand {
    $a->{brand} cmp $b->{brand}
}
```

Complexity is the key; can start with numeric or alphabetic character.
The Brand or PO can be of different size, as well. The delimiter may be a dot or hypen.

Can we solve this depending on the input received in `$arr_ref`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close. You just need to remove the `[` and `]` brackets and dereference the array you want to assign to `@$array_ref = ...`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $arr_ref = [
  { brand => "B.3", PO => "1.c", supplier => "Y" },
  { brand => "B.2", PO => "2.b", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "B.1", PO => "1.b", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "A.2", PO => "2.a", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "A.1", PO => "1.a", supplier => "X" },
];

my @sorted = sort { $a->{brand} cmp $b->{brand} } @$arr_ref;

use Data::Dump;
dd @sorted;
```

Output:

```
(
  { brand => "A.1", PO => "1.a", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "A.2", PO => "2.a", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "B.1", PO => "1.b", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "B.2", PO => "2.b", supplier => "X" },
  { brand => "B.3", PO => "1.c", supplier => "Y" },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort it using [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) and correct comparator for each field.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $arr_ref = [
    { brand => "A.1", PO => "1.a", supplier => "X" },
    { brand => "A.2", PO => "2.a", supplier => "X" },
    { brand => "B.1", PO => "1.b", supplier => "X" },
    { brand => "B.2", PO => "2.b", supplier => "X" },
    { brand => "B.3", PO => "1.c", supplier => "Y" },
];
my @sorted = map $_->[0], sort {
           $a->[1][0] cmp $b->[1][0]
        or $a->[1][1] <=> $b->[1][1]
        or $a->[1][2] <=> $b->[1][2]
        or $a->[1][3] cmp $b->[1][3]
    } map [ $_, [ map split( /[.-]/, $_, 2 ), @$_{qw(brand PO)} ] ],
    @$arr_ref;
print Dumper( \@sorted );
```

Try use brand `"A.10"` to spot the difference.

Comment: `[ map split(/[.-]/, $_, 2), @$_{qw(brand PO)} ]` if you like it DRY.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sort method:

```
sub by_brand_or_po {
    my ($a_ba, $a_bn) = split /\.|-/, $a->{brand};
    my ($b_ba, $b_bn) = split /\.|-/, $b->{brand};

    my ($a_pa, $a_pn) = split /\.|-/, $a->{PO};
    my ($b_pa, $b_pn) = split /\.|-/, $b->{PO};

    return( $a_ba cmp $b_ba or $a_bn <=> $b_bn or
            $a_pa cmp $b_pa or $a_pn <=> $b_pn );
}
```

It prioritizes the brand alpha over numeric over PO alpha over PO numeric, and will split over a dot or hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

use [Sort::Key::Natural](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort%3a%3aKey%3a%3aNatural)!

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natkeysort);

my @sorted_by_brand = natkeysort { $_->{brand} } @data;
my @sorted_by_po = natkeysort { $_->{po} } @data;
```