# How do I sort a perl hash by multiple keys?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

Hi I have a data structure which is of the following form:

```
$data = {                                                                                           
    'a' => { key1 => 2, key2 => 1 },                                                                   
    'b' => { key1 => 1, key2 => 2 },                                                                   
    'c' => { key1 => 1, key2 => 1 },                                                                   
    'd' => { key1 => 3, key2 => 2 },                                                                   
    'e' => { key1 => 3, key2 => 1 },                                                                   
    'f' => { key1 => 1, key2 => 2 },                                                                   
};
```

what I want to be able to do is loop through this data structure in ascending order of `key2`, descending order of `key1`, and then ascending order of the hash key, e.g:

```
e
a
c
d
b
f
```

how can I achieve this in perl? I know that I can sort the hash by key using `sort keys %$data`, but how can I sort by multiple values and keys?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A similar question has been asked before and can be found here:
[Sorting an Array of Hash by multiple keys Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395383/sorting-an-array-of-hash-by-multiple-keys-perl)

Basically, Perl has two operators for sorting, `<=>` and `cmp` which return -1, 0 or 1, depending on if the left hand side is less than, equal to, or greater than the right hand side. `<=>` is used for numerical comparison, and `cmp` is used for stringwise comparison. More detail about their use can be found here: [Equality Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).

These operators can be used with Perl's [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function and in conjuction with the `or` operator can be used to achieve the result you're after:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = {
    'a' => { key1 => 2, key2 => 1 },
    'b' => { key1 => 1, key2 => 2 },
    'c' => { key1 => 1, key2 => 1 },
    'd' => { key1 => 3, key2 => 2 },
    'e' => { key1 => 3, key2 => 1 },
    'f' => { key1 => 1, key2 => 2 },
};

my @sorted = sort {
        $data->{$a}->{key2} <=> $data->{$b}->{key2} or
        $data->{$b}->{key1} <=> $data->{$a}->{key1} or
        $a cmp $b
    } keys %{$data};

for my $key (@sorted){
    print "$key\n";
}
```

Since `<=>` and `cmp` return 0 (false) for equality, it means we can chain equality checks together with `or` or `||`.

In the example above we `$a` and `$b` to refer to a key of the `$data` hashref at a particular iteration of the sort. Using these keys we can access particular values of the hash, e.g. `$data->{$a}->{key2}`. By putting `$a` before `$b` it will cause the sort to be in ascending order, and putting `$b` before `$a` will cause the sort to be in descending order.